# ajax animation Control

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have a popup login in my webform .I tried to use the ajax animation control for the panel ,means popup.when i click a hyperlink i want to fadein popup.how can i use the animation control correctly?
Anybody knowsw please help me.. thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this [control](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx):

The confirm button control from the AJAX Toolkit seems to be what you need.